# How to send internal array in json when i want to send it to the webservice with SoapClient in php7

Tags: php, json, web-services, soap-client

I'm working with a fly web service.I should to be able to create following json format and send to the server :

```
{
 "FareSourceCode": "313139353639393726323426363636323231",
  "SessionId": "53a2210f-b151-4aa1-bef0-3db2dbe71565",
  "TravelerInfo": {
    "PhoneNumber": "02012345678",
    "Email": "Sales@partocrs.com",
    "AirTravelers": [
      {
        "DateOfBirth": "1990-11-01T00:00:00",
        "Gender": 0,
        "PassengerType": 1,
        "PassengerName": {
          "PassengerFirstName": "John",
          "PassengerLastName": "Smith",
          "PassengerTitle": 0
        },
        "Passport": {
          "Country": "US",
          "ExpiryDate": "2020-05-06T00:00:00",
          "PassportNumber": "AB1234567"
        },
        "NationalId": "0012230877",
        "Nationality": "US",
        "ExtraServiceId": [
          "sample string 1"
        ],
        "FrequentFlyerNumber": "123456789",
        "SeatPreference": 0,
        "MealPreference": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I use SoapClient in php7 with this code :

```
<?php
    $PassengerData = //Get passengers informations from mysql
    $AirTravelers = array();

    foreach ($PassengerData as $p) {
        $PassengerType = 'Adt'; //Adult
        $PassengerTitle = ($p->sex) ? 'Mrs' : 'Mr';
        $AirTravelers = [
            'DateOfBirth' => $p->age,
            'Gender' => $p->sex ? 'Female' : 'Male',
            'PassengerType' => $PassengerType,
            'PassengerName' => [
                'PassengerFirstName' => $p->efname,
                'PassengerLastName' => $p->elname,
                'PassengerTitle' => $PassengerTitle,
            ],
            'Passport' => [
                'Country' => 'IR',
                'ExpiryDate' => $p->passport_expire,
                'PassportNumber' => $p->passport_number,
            ],
            'NationalId' => $p->ncode,
            'Nationality' => 'IR',
            'SeatPreference' => 'Any',
            'MealPreference' => 'Any',
        ];
    }

    $client = new \SoapClient($ServerHttp);
    $session = $client->CreateSession(array("rq" => [ "OfficeId" => $PartoOfficeId, "UserName" => $PartoUserName, "Password" => $PartoPassword]));

    $AirBook = $client->AirBook(
            array("rq" => [
                    'FareSourceCode' => $FareSourceCode,
                    'SessionId' => $session->CreateSessionResult->SessionId,
                    'TravelerInfo' => ['PhoneNumber' => $current_user_data->mobile,
                    'Email' => $current_user_data->user_name,
                    'AirTravelers' =>$AirTravelers
                    ]
                ]
            )
    );
```

But this code can't make correct json format.Because php output json like this :

```
"AirTravelers": **[**{...}**]**
```

When i see json log(with json_encode):

```
json_encode([
        'FareSourceCode' => $FareSourceCode,
        'SessionId' => $session->CreateSessionResult->SessionId,
        'TravelerInfo' => ['PhoneNumber' => $current_user_data->mobile,
            'Email' => $current_user_data->user_name,
            'AirTravelers' => $AirTravelers
        ]
    ])
```

It is like this (php output json):

```
"AirTravelers": **{**
```

And When i use this code :

```
json_encode([
        'FareSourceCode' => $FareSourceCode,
        'SessionId' => $session->CreateSessionResult->SessionId,
        'TravelerInfo' => ['PhoneNumber' => $current_user_data->mobile,
            'Email' => $current_user_data->user_name,
            'AirTravelers' => **[**$AirTravelers**]**
        ]
    ])
```

Json output format were as follows:

```
 $AirTravelers = **[**{....}]**strong text**
```

My question is :How can i send correct json format to this web service?
I use json_encode in my php request but it doesn't work and when i use :

```
 $AirBook = $client->AirBook(
            array("rq" => [
                    'FareSourceCode' => $FareSourceCode,
                    'SessionId' => $session->CreateSessionResult->SessionId,
                    'TravelerInfo' => ['PhoneNumber' => $current_user_data->mobile,
                    'Email' => $current_user_data->user_name,
                    'AirTravelers' =>[$AirTravelers]
                    ]
                ]
            )
    );
```

I receive this error in php :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:DeserializationFailed ] The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:rq. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type ServiceModel.Request.AirBook. The value '1988-11-16 00:00:00' cannot be parsed as the type 'DateTime'.'. Please see InnerException for more details. in C:\wamp64 \www\paradise\wp-content\plugins\amir_traveler\fly\fly_functions.php on line 341

 SoapFault: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:rq. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type ServiceModel.Request.AirBook. The value '1988-11-16 00:00:00' cannot be parsed as the type 'DateTime'.'. Please see InnerException for more details. in C:\wamp64\www\paradise\wp-content\plugins\amir_traveler\fly\fly_functions.php on line 341
```

Comment: Where did you log your json (cli, browser, file)? Are you sure it does not come from any other scripts or devtools?

Comment: Where did you log your json?:Browser,
Are you sure it does not come from any other scripts or devtools?
Yes I am.